# Add field separately to firestore document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following code creates a firestore collection and adds data to it:

```
function saveID(sender_psid,complete){
   let data = new Object();
   data.ID = sender_psid;
   data.TASK = complete;
   data.TIME = new Date();
   db.collection('users').add(data);
}
```

I want to create another function which adds a field to the document at a different time. I have the following function but am getting the error "TypeError: collectionRef.update is not a function"

```
function saveImage(sender_psid,image) {


  let collectionRef = db.collection('users');


  collectionRef.update({IMG:image}).then(res => {
  console.log(`Document updated at ${res.updateTime}`);
});
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Build a [DocumentReference](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/DocumentReference) to the document you want to update, then use the [update()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.14.x/DocumentReference#update) method on the DocumentReference to indicate only the fields to be added or changed.  Pass it an object with only properties that match the fields to add or change.

Comment: Do I build the reference in the second function?

Comment: Build it wherever you need to use it.  If you don't need a DocumentReference, then don't bother.

Comment: You built a reference to a collection, not a document within that collection.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) documentation, There is a better way

```
const cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');

const res = await cityRef.set({
  capital: true
}, { merge: true });
```

Answer (score 3):

Flutter Example:

```
var userDoc = Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('replaceIdHere');
userDoc.updateData({'fieldName':'newValue'});
```